# Black screen when booting ArchLinux from USB stick on Chromebook R11

Tags: arch-linux, boot, chrome-book, syslinux

I've recently got an Acer Chromebook R11 cyan and I would like to be able to boot ArchLinux from it. For now I would like to boot from an USB drive.

I made a pretty classic ArchLinux installation on it (syslinux as bootloader, DOS partition table, one ext4 partition for /boot and one btrfs partition with two subvolumes for / and /home).

I did set the Chromebook to developper mode, enabled legacy and usb boot and installed John Lewis RW_LEGACY.

Booting from the USB drive works well on other computers, however on the Chromebook, while syslinux runs fine (albeit very slowly) and is able to boot Arch, the classic "loading initramfs/probing edd" output is followed by a totally black screen.

I did try some kernel options (nomodeset, nofb, vga=normal, video=vesafb:off, i915.modeset=0), hoping that it might help getting an output on screen, with no result.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I'm an assclown. I completely forgot to try the fallback initramfs image, which boots successfully (although it doesn't recognize my keyboard but this is another problem).